# The other animations are not played when I delete idle animation

Tags: unity, animation

I'm using [Cyber Monsters 2](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/characters/creatures/cyber-monsters-2-161380) asset and found some weird stuff. If I delete idle animation or move it away, the other animations stop working and the monster stays in T-pose. When I check the animator, active animations are marked as playing but the actual animation is not played. What could be the reason?

Comment: A minority of users know how this model is set up. You might want to edit your question to show us how the asset is set up so that you increase your chances of getting more/better answers.

Answer (score 0):

The prefab in the asset had an animator component with the avatar from idle animation. When I re-assigned another avatar, things started to work again.